# clickable image within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a swipe gesture working the way I would like, when the user swipes from right/left the images toggle.  Now I just want to add a different link to each img src, so slider1 has a different link associated to it then slider2, etc.  Can someone please help me figure this out?

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='swipe.js'></script>

<title>Presentation</title>
<style>

.swipe {
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}

#mySwipe div b {
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    margin-top:240px;
    background:url("");
    height:1280px;
    width:720px;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // When the DOM is ready, initialize the scripts.
    jQuery(function( $ ){

    // Get a reference to the container.
    var container = $( ".container" );


    // Bind the link to toggle the slide.
    $( "a" ).click(
    function( event ){
    // Prevent the default event.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Toggle the slide based on its current
    // visibility.
    if (container.is( ":visible" )){

    // Hide - slide up.
    container.slideUp(500, function(){ $('').show(); });
    } else {

    // Show - slide down.
    container.slideDown(300, function(){ $('').hide(); });
    }
    }
    );

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#"><img src="../question_header/question.png" /></a>
<div class="nfooter"></div>

<div id='mySwipe' style='width:720px; height:981px; margin-top:55px;' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider1.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider2.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider3.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider4.png" /></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

// pure JS
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
  // transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
});

// with jQuery
// window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');

</script>

<div class='container'>
<div class='inner'>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: You know you call jQuery before it is included with this code/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### THIRD ANSWER:Change image [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/dkR7g/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


   $('img[slideurl]').click(function(){

   if($(this).is(':last-child')){
       $(this).insertBefore($('img[slideUrl]').first());
    } 
    else {
     $(this).next('img[slideUrl]').insertBefore($(this));

    }

 });

});
```

### SECOND ANSWER:

After i read your comments ,i suggest using jQuery,to add a `click` event to every `img` that has a custo attribute , for example `slideUrl='http://stackoverflow.com'` :

**HTML:**

```
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider1.png" slideUrl='http://link1.com' /></div>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider2.png"  slideUrl='http://link2.com'/></div>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider3.png"  slideUrl='http://link3.com'/></div>
    <div><img src="../slider/slider4.png"  slideUrl='http://link4.com'/></div>
  </div>
```

**JS code:**

```
$('img[slideUrl]').click(function(){
window.location.href = $(this).attr('slideUrl');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
img[slideUrl]{
 cursor:pointer; 
}
```

### FIRST ANSWER:

You can do it using `<a>` element with `href` attribute like this :

```
 <div><a href='link1'><img src="../slider/slider1.png" /></a></div>
```

Comment: the problem is every time I try using the standard 'a' tag, it just keeps pulling up the the link that's tied to the inner class (even though its assigned to a different button).  And I don't want that. I added additional code, so you have the entire picture.

Comment: @need2nobasis try my second solution

Comment: this is great, thanks.  Now if I wanted it to be a png image and open on top of the selected img src, can this code do that as well?

Comment: @need2nobasis more details please

Comment: for example, right now there are slider1 - slider4.  When I select one of the sliders, instead or redirecting to a website, it would call up an image instead.  basically the image will act as an overlay on the screen.

Comment: it's possible , but which image you want to be the overlay ?

Comment: the slideURL image would be the overlay

Comment: @need2nobasis which one you want , if i click the seconde image for example , which image it will be the overlay

Comment: there would be 4 different images, a specific one for each slider1.  slider1 pulls image1.png, slider2 pulls image2.png, etc.

Comment: check the latest solution

Comment: right now the demo toggles the different icons when you select one.  I am trying to have an image appear as an overlay on top of the existing image. It would be similar to clicking on the Chrome logo and the twitter logo appears on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
<div>
    <a href='link1' style="display: block; height: 100%">
    <img src="../slider/slider1.png" alt=".." />
</a> </div>
```

This will make the entire `<div>` clickable.

Comment: the problem is every time I try using the standard 'a' tag, it just keeps pulling up the the link that's tied to the inner class (even though its assigned to a different button).  And I don't want that. I added additional code, so you have the entire picture.